# Hide some dynamic levels on Flexicious Datagrid

Tags: flexicious

Using ultimate flexicious datagrid with enableDynamicLevels="true", I search a way to hide the last two dynamic level created on flexicious datagrid(using a groupingcollection). For example: in the groupLabel column, I have the following tree

```
>2010
 >Jan
  >weeks
   >regions
```

I want to show only

```
>2010
 >Jan
```

Is is possible ?

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic levels is designed to support building levels from the dataprovider. In this case it appears you only want to build 2 levels, so why use dynamic levels to begin with? Just specify a fixed number of levels in your grid markup and it will only nest 2 levels deep.